# Filter a list based on another list containing IEnumerable<Guid> using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ienumerable, guid

I am looking for a way to filter a list based on another list that contains only the ids. If List A does not contain any of the ids in listOfGuids, get the filtered List that does not contain the ids

```
IEnumerable<Guid> listOfGuids = some list of Guid.
var filteredList = ListA.All(x=>listOfGuids.Where(x=>x.id!={all the items in list of Guid}))
```

Eg:

```
listOfGuids = {
    "9c105700-98af-4c23-92ac-fd2dc5664b7a",
    "7d6e0918-fb05-4b37-80f4-c7e5ccaa094d"
}

ListA =[
    {id="9c105700-98af-4c23-92ac-fd2dc5664b7a", name="abc"},
    {id="7d6e0918-fb05-4b37-80f4-c7e5ccaa094d", name="def"},
    {id="6fb0bcf3-9ca6-40c8-9fa1-f7557ef09558", name="ghi"}
]
```

Should return filteredList as

```
[{{id="6fb0bcf3-9ca6-40c8-9fa1-f7557ef09558", name = "ghi"}}]
```

Comment: Your results don't match your conditions. The `id` in the result set _is_ in the list of guids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want items `Where` it's not true that the list `Contains` the `id`:

```
var filteredList = ListA.Where(x => !listOfGuids.Contains(x.id))
```